# Select element but deselect specified child of element

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

Just curious if this is possible in jsoup

Select an element and it's text but deselect a specified child.

```html
<div>
  <p><strong>Location: </strong> Earth</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to return just `Earth`?

Edit: Also, in the paragraph, Location is static, but Earth is not.
i.e you can have

```
Location: Earth
Location: LA
Location: Mars
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `Element::ownText` method.

```
String html = "<div>\n" + //
        "<p><strong>Location: </strong> Earth</p>\n" + //
        "</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element p = doc.select("p").first();

if (p!=null) {
    System.out.println(p.ownText());
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Earth
```

Comment: http://try.jsoup.org/ I tried using the `Elment::ownText` method here but it said it was not recognized

Comment: @TrevorWood On try.jsoup.org you can test CSS selectors only. CSS selectors can't match text nodes. The API must be used here.